# it fails when git-receive-pack has new line in return

Tags: git

I am trying to response to a git-receive-pack request, so if my program return

```
009c0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 capabilities^{}report-status delete-refs side-band-64k quiet atomic ofs-delta agent=git/2.10.1.(Apple.Git-78)
```

it works and git clients like smartgit will work as well but when the return value has a new line (\n) with 0000 in response just like standard

```
009c0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 capabilities^{}report-status delete-refs side-band-64k quiet atomic ofs-delta agent=git/2.10.1.(Apple.Git-78)
0000
```

it does not work and client show me

```
/test.git/info/refs not valid: is this a git repository
```

what is the problem? I just do as https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Transfer-Protocols says.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

From the document you link to:

> The git-receive-pack command immediately responds with one line for each reference it currently has – in this case, just the master branch and its SHA-1. The first line also has a list of the server’s capabilities (here, report-status, delete-refs, and some others, including the client identifier).

Where are you getting `capabilities` as a ref name from? The error message you are seeing suggests that this is not the format that is expected, and I see no mention of it (as a ref name) in the transfer protocols document. I'd suggest trying `refs/heads/master` as the document uses, and branching out from there.